# Adding n Hours from a field to a timestamp column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 column. I need to add hour field to column_A . Column_A is a timestamp and HR column is number

| COLUMN_A | HR |
| --- | --- |
| 14-09-20 01:24:45.000000000 AM | 6 |
| 28-08-20 07:41:01.000000000 AM | 6 |
| 15-10-20 10:46:37.000000000 PM |  |
| 22-09-20 07:33:53.000000000 AM |  |
| 01-10-20 01:11:10.000000000 AM | 12 |
| 30-09-20 01:54:22.000000000 AM | 12 |
| 07-10-20 10:39:30.000000000 PM | 6 |
| 13-12-20 02:25:40.000000000 PM | 1 |

Answer (score 3):

Add an interval:

```sql
SELECT column_a + COALESCE(HR, 0) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR AS updated_column_a
FROM   table_name
```

or:

```sql
SELECT column_a + NUMTODSINTERVAL(COALESCE(HR, 0), 'HOUR') AS updated_column_a
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (COLUMN_A, HR) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-09-14 01:24:45.000000000',    6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 07:41:01.000000000',    6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-10-15 22:46:37.000000000', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-09-22 07:33:53.000000000', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-10-01 01:11:10.000000000',   12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-09-30 01:54:22.000000000',   12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-10-07 22:39:30.000000000',    6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-12-13 02:25:40.000000000',    1 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| UPDATED_COLUMN_A |
| --- |
| 2020-09-14 07:24:45.000000000 |
| 2020-08-28 13:41:01.000000000 |
| 2020-10-15 22:46:37.000000000 |
| 2020-09-22 07:33:53.000000000 |
| 2020-10-01 13:11:10.000000000 |
| 2020-09-30 13:54:22.000000000 |
| 2020-10-08 04:39:30.000000000 |
| 2020-12-13 03:25:40.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c0TExLH7)

Answer (score 0):

Add the hr only if is is not null and divide by 24.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN HR IS NULL THEN COLUMN_A ELSE COLUMN_A + HR/24 END) AS COLUMN_A_HR FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: Adding numbers will implicitly cast the timestamp to a date which will lose the fractional seconds [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qP8ERKCO)

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE statement with the DATEADD function. Here's how you can do it:

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET COLUMN_A = DATEADD(hour, HR, COLUMN_A)
WHERE HR IS NOT NULL;
```

Replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table. This SQL statement will add the hour value from the HR column to the timestamp value in Column_A for all rows where HR is not NULL.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATEADD` function.

Comment: It also seems unlikely they want to update the timestamp value in the table, as the hour value is in the same row, not from some external source. It isn't specified but it sounds like they want a query result with the modified value, not an update.

Comment: That's true, the other solution can be by using the ``INTERVAL`` datatype and the ``NUMTODSINTERVAL`` function to add hours to a timestamp. Here's how you can rewrite the SQL statement for Oracle: ``UPDATE your_table_name
SET COLUMN_A = COLUMN_A + NUMTODSINTERVAL(HR, 'HOUR')
WHERE HR IS NOT NULL;``